# Arokh HaShulchan and pocket square tzitzith

Tags: clothing, tzitzis, shiurim-measurements, aruch-hashulchan

According to the *Arokh HaShulchan* ([OC 16:5](http://www.sefaria.org/Aruch_HaShulchan.1.16.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) [that there is no size limit on garments to require *tzitzith*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71836/8775), does that mean a pocket square is obligated in *tzitzith*?

[image: pocket square]

Comment: ג' אצבעות על ג' אצבעות

Comment: Perhaps include the relevant quote? I don't think that's an accurate representation of his position.

Comment: Do you wear a pocket square? What about a wallet? Cellphone? Seems like you're just carrying it

Comment: To add to Double's last comment there is a difference between levisha and halaah. Levisha allows us to walk out into a reshus harabim on shabbos. Halaah (i.e. placing your folded talis on your shoulder and walking out like that) is a melacha deoraisa of Hotzaah.

Comment: @DoubleAA Pocket squares are worn as decorative accesories (as distict perhaps from handkerchiefs).  If you are wearing your wallet/cellphone solely as a tachshit, perhaps you should consider appending tzitzis.

Comment: @Loewian "solely" Certainly people have decorative cell phone cases, etc. Are you suggesting that having an additional purpose besides decoration should matter? What if my coat also keeps me warm?

Comment: A *pocket square* is not a separate garment.

Comment: @sabbahillel A pocket square is a decorative handkerchief folded a particular way and worn protruding from a lapel pocket as an ornamental men's accessory, akin to a necktie.

Comment: That sounds like it is not a *beged* and would not require tzitzis since it is not worn.

Comment: @sabbahillel That depends on how you define a *beged*.  If you have sources for this distinction though, that sounds like an answer. (Relatedly, what makes a tiny *tallit katan* a *beged*?)

Comment: I do not have sources as of now, just memory. I think that a beged is something worn front and back (like a *tallis katan*) Thus if a t-shirt were slit up the sides to have four corners, it would reqire tzitzis. Since the handkerchief is **carried** in one's pocket, it is not a beged.